# Adding row into database

Tags: c#, sql-server, class

I have a button, each time I click this button the new row is added to the database as long as the text I introduce into the textbox is not in the database.Otherwise, i get the error(something like -violation of primary key the duplicate key is ("the last row that I added with success into the database").And I'm getting this error after I click the button even the text I introduce after into textbox is not in the database, I have to restart the program, and then again..whats the problem?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataRow rows = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        //this is primary key
        rows[2] = textBox4.Text;
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(rows);
    try
    {
        //updating database.
        objConnect.UpdateDatabase(ds);
        MessageBox.Show("Record Saved");
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like objConnect.UpdateDatabase is trying to insert instead of update? But we have no way of knowing what that method is doing.

Comment: here is the class https://jsfiddle.net/o1cd14xv/

Comment: try to run simple update command rather than using data adapter, you are adding row to data set and trying to update it, but you are not refreshing data set after update.

Comment: Could i have i siquence of code?im new in c#

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite code using following syntax. There are many sophisticated methods are available, but since you are beginner to C# , i think this will be best for you to learn.

```
    // Create connection object

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionStringtoYourDB");

    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

    try {

        // Open the connection.

        connection.Open();

        // Execute the insert command.

        command.CommandText = String.Concat("INSERT INTO Your_Tbl(FirstName) VALUES('", textBox4.Text,"')");

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Saved");

    }
 catch (Exception err)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }
    finally {

        // Close the connection.

        connection.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first checking to see if the key exists in the table, if not add it and get the new primary key, if exists then do nothing other than inform the user.

Here I have a table for a hospital departments (there is only two columns to keep things simple).

Here I'm using a class to keep data operations separated from the form.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Operations
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Replace with your SQL Server name
        /// </summary>
        private string Server = "KARENS-PC";
        /// <summary>
        /// Database in which data resides, see SQL_Script.sql
        /// </summary>
        private string Catalog = "ForumExamples";
        /// <summary>
        /// Connection string for connecting to the database
        /// </summary>
        private string ConnectionString = "";
        /// <summary>
        /// Setup the connection string
        /// </summary>
        public Operations()
        {
            ConnectionString = $"Data Source={Server};Initial Catalog={Catalog};Integrated Security=True";
        }
        public bool InsertDepartment(string pDepartment, ref int pIdentifier)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection { ConnectionString = ConnectionString })
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand { Connection = cn })
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Departments WHERE Name = @Name";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", pDepartment);

                    cn.Open();
                    if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = @"
                        INSERT INTO dbo.Departments (Name) 
                        VALUES (@Name); SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);";
                        pIdentifier = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form code, one button, one text box

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDepartmentName.Text))
        {
            int id = 0;
            Operations ops = new Operations();
            if (ops.InsertDepartment(txtDepartmentName.Text, ref id))
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Id for '{txtDepartmentName.Text}' is {id}");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Department '{txtDepartmentName.Text}' is already in the database table");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a department name");
        }
    }
}
```

Some parts of the above code are for SQL-Server e.g. how the new primary key is retrieved yet with a little modification can be done with MS-Access or other databases.